# Extend Django Admin Tools template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way I can override the `brand` block of `django-admin-tools`, which extends from Django's `admin` app?

If there is, how?

I tried placing `base_site.html` in one of the `templates` folders of my project, but Django is not picking it up, assumably because `django-admin-tools` has priority over the other templates because of the order of the apps in my settings. But if I change the order, `django-admin-tools` stops working as it's required to be at the top in my settings.

Comment: try to change order inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` put your app before `django-admin-tools`.

Comment: @BearBrown If I change the order and add my app before `django-admin-tools`, I can extend from Django's admin `admin/base_site.html`, but then `django-admin-tools` stops working.

Comment: may be here https://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#customizing-the-dashboards

Comment: @BearBrown the templates I can override there don't extend from `base` nor `base_site`, which means that they don't have access to the `brand` block.